# Print iso-8583 message using JPOS library

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

How could I print packed ISO messages for example in the following code?

```
ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
isoMsg.setMTI("0200");
isoMsg.set(2, "16");
isoMsg.set(2, "5421287475388412");
isoMsg.set(3, "000000   ");
isoMsg.set(4, "400.0");
isoMsg.set(7, "0716070815");
isoMsg.set(11, "844515");

logISOMsg(isoMsg);

byte[] data = isoMsg.pack();
System.out.println("RESULT : " + new String(data));
```

Answer (score 9):

Hi if you want to print field by field, the easiest way is to use the ISOMsg.dump() method, in your code would be:

```
isoMsg.dump(Sytsem.out, "");
```

If you want an hex dump representation you can use ISOUtil.hexDump() method, in your example:

```
import org.jpos.iso.ISOException;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg;
import org.jpos.iso.ISOUtil;

public class JposExamples {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public JposExamples() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException{
        ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        isoMsg.setPackager(new ISO87BPackager());
        isoMsg.setMTI("0200");
        isoMsg.set(2, "16");
        isoMsg.set(2, "5421287475388412");
        isoMsg.set(3, "000000");
        isoMsg.set(4, "400.0");
        isoMsg.set(7, "0716070815");
        isoMsg.set(11, "844515");
        byte[] data = isoMsg.pack();
        System.out.println(ISOUtil.hexdump(data));
    }
}
```

This would use ISO87BPackager and print this:

```
0000  02 00 72 20 00 00 00 00  00 00 16 54 21 28 74 75  ..r .......T!(tu
0010  38 84 12 00 00 00 00 00  00 04 00 E0 07 16 07 08  8...............
0020  15 84 45 15                                       ..E.
```

If you use ISO87APackager instead output would be like this:

```
0000  30 32 30 30 37 32 32 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  0200722000000000
0010  30 30 30 30 31 36 35 34  32 31 32 38 37 34 37 35  0000165421287475
0020  33 38 38 34 31 32 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  3884120000000000
0030  30 30 30 34 30 30 2E 30  30 37 31 36 30 37 30 38  000400.007160708
0040  31 35 38 34 34 35 31 35                           15844515
```

Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to print the message field by field, you can see the article in this [link](http://jimmod.com/blog/2011/07/26/jimmys-blog-iso-8583-tutorial-build-and-parse-iso-message-using-jpos-library/).

I refer his code here:

```
public class BuildISOMessage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ISOException {
        // Create Packager based on XML that contain DE type
        GenericPackager packager = new GenericPackager("basic.xml");

        // Create ISO Message
        ISOMsg isoMsg = new ISOMsg();
        isoMsg.setPackager(packager);
        isoMsg.setMTI("0200");
        isoMsg.set(3, "201234");
        isoMsg.set(4, "10000");
        isoMsg.set(7, "110722180");
        isoMsg.set(11, "123456");
        isoMsg.set(44, "A5DFGR");
        isoMsg.set(105, "ABCDEFGHIJ 1234567890");

        // print the DE list
        logISOMsg(isoMsg);

        // Get and print the output result
        byte[] data = isoMsg.pack();
        System.out.println("RESULT : " + new String(data));
    }

    private static void logISOMsg(ISOMsg msg) {
        System.out.println("----ISO MESSAGE-----");
        try {
            System.out.println("  MTI : " + msg.getMTI());
            for (int i=1;i&lt;=msg.getMaxField();i++) {
                if (msg.hasField(i)) {
                    System.out.println("    Field-"+i+" : "+msg.getString(i));
                }
            }
        } catch (ISOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have already seen jimmy's blog, there is problem with generating bitmap, i need custom made ISOMsg, how can i make custom made ISOMsg ?

Comment: If you want custom ISOMsg structure you can try with own implementation of packager, check out package [org.jpos.iso.packager]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the raw message this is what worked for me:

```html
ISOBasePackager packager = new Reliance93APackagerBBitmap();
org.jpos.util.Logger jPosLogger = new org.jpos.util.Logger();
jPosLogger.addListener(new SimpleLogListener(System.out));
packager.setLogger(jPosLogger, "deb
```